# Storing different types inside a list?

Tags: c#, arrays

Related: [A list of multiple data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343336/a-list-of-multiple-data-types)

I want to know how to store different array types (including system types) inside an array.

The above question covered how to create a list that will allow only user-defined classes by using interfaces.  But what if I want a list that will accept only doubles and strings?  What about doubles and a class I wrote?  What about a list that will accept only a class a wrote and a class someone else wrote (so I can't add an interface to the 3rd party class, I think).

I considered using `List<object>`, but I don't know if that's the accepted best practice.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new to C#.

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? If you think you have that need, probably there's a better way to approach what you are building. Specially if the types have no relationship whatsoever between them.

Comment: Yeah, but what if I want a list that accepts only doubles and strings, and nothing else?

Comment: @FranciscoSoto I agree... every time I've dealt with code where someone used `List<object>`, it's been a fantabulous world of runtime errors.

Comment: Are the items interlaced? Like one string, then one double, then one string, etc. where each string is related to the double? If so, use List<Tuple<string, double>>

Comment: @Deflect, as Francisco Soto said, if you can tell us what you are doing this for, we could help better. Otherwise stick with `List<object>` which is definitely is not the best practice in many cases.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Did any of the answers provide a solution?

Comment: @Michael0x2a Accept an answer. It's the least you can do to give credit to the people who helped you.

Comment: @Stefan -- none of the answers here satisfactorily answered the question in a way that was helpful to me six years ago. Actually, now that I'm looking back on this question with the hindsight of experience, all of these answers are wrong. The correct answer would have been a frame challenge similar to the ones in the comments: something more like "what you're trying to do is not possible to do cleanly since C# doesn't have union types/is likely also an antipattern; the best thing to do is to redesign your code".

Comment: @Michael0x2a Then supply the correct answer yourself and accept it (if that is possible). This way, other people who have the same issues can use your experience and knowledge as well.

Comment: @Stefan -- No, I don't think I will. The comments already say everything worth saying about this question and repeating them near-verbatim in an answer is redundant. If future readers decide to ignore this information, that is really their problem, not mine. More broadly, my conclusion is that this question as written has currently has no satisfactory answer. If C# ever does end up adding language features such as union types that can support this pattern cleanly, I may change my mind, but until then my decision to not accept an answer is a deliberate and intentional one.

Answer (score 9):

You can specify not only custom types. `List<int>`, `List<double>`, `List<string>` will works as well. If you need to store mixed types - you need to specify closest base class for all types. In `List<object>` can be stored instance of any type.

Comment: This will, however, not allow you to access the properties of the types inside the array. I.e. If you try to have a `List<type1|type2>` so you name it `List<object>` to encompass type1 and type2. You will not be able to search `List.FirstOrDefault(i => i.PropertyOfType1AndType2)` (assuming type1&type2 have the similar property).

Comment: @FranciscoSoto I think you are right. This shouldn't be needed if you are writing your code from scratch. It's important to write quality, well-thought out code. Though sometimes it's important to know how to do something dirty if you need to do some magic -- to please a customer for eg.

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to give away type safety you can use an [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx), which was the only way to use a list of stuff pre generics.

You can put some wrapper code around it to only accept doubles and strings.

Comment: Can you add anything to an ArrayList? For example, int, string, Person? How do you do to get an element? you have to cast it?

Answer (score 3):

You should create a class

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string x {get;set;}
    public double y{get;set;}
}
```

Then just create an array of that class. This class can have whatever types you want, that's the beauty of having objects in an object oriented language.

```
public MyClass[] someList=new MyClass[insert_number_of_elements];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom collection in which you implement Add() method which only accepts doubles and string, something like:

```
void Add(object toAdd)
{
     if (toAdd is string)
         // add into inner collection ... 
      ... (same for double)
}
```

But, to be honest, I really can't think of any way that you would need a collection that accepts only these two types. You can probably solve the problem some other way...

Answer (score 2):

You also can use the ? option, make a list of the following type:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string? x {get;set;}
    public double? y {get;set;}
}
```

This way you can select if none, one or both can have a value.

Or if you don't like the HasValue/Value functions:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public enum EType { String, Double };

    EType TypeFilled {get; private set }

    string _x;
    public string X { get { return _x; }; set { _x = value; TypeFilled = EType.String; }
    double y;
    public double y { get { return _y; }; set { _y = value; TypeFilled = EType.Double; }
}
```

This way the typeFilled property decides what is filled. You could add validation to prevent being set twice etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know that I'm a little late to the party, but I do this all the time.  Especially when I'm initializing new classes.  I like to do the heavy lifting outside of my main method, so I use object arrays to handle it.  `Object[]` lets you put whatever you want into the array.  then, when you return the array, you cast the array value to whatever you want.  for example:

```
int NewInt = (int)InitArray[0];
string NewString = (String)InitArray[1];
double NewDouble = (Double)InitArray[2];
```

That might not be the most elegant solution in all cases, but for the work I do, it certainly handles the single output problem nicely.