# How to combine two list of different objects into one list by combining one element from each list?

Tags: c#, list

Hi I am trying to combine two lists with different objects.

```
[{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-0.015270888805389405,
"y":9.267399787902832},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":1}],

"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":1,"notemsg":"Added one"}]},
{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-0.015270888805389405,
"y":9.267399787902832},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2},{"id":1,
"allposition":{"x":-0.02840942144393921,"y":6.721944808959961},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":2}],
"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":2,"notemsg":"Added two"}]},
{"SaveValues":[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-0.015270888805389405,
"y":9.267399787902832},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":3},{"id":1,
"allposition":{"x":-0.02840942144393921,"y":6.721944808959961},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},
"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"movetype":3},{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-0.10085266828536987,
"y":4.49822473526001},"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},
"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":3}],"NoteValues":
[{"movenumber":3,"notemsg":"Added three"}]},{"SaveValues":
[{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":-0.015270888805389405,"y":9.267399787902832}
,"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},

"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":4},{"id":1,
"allposition":{"x":-0.02840942144393921,"y":6.721944808959961},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":4},{"id":1,"allposition"
:{"x":-0.10085266828536987,"y":4.49822473526001},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},
"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},
"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},
"movetype":4},{"id":1,"allposition":{"x":0.17862117290496827,"y":1.5408382415771485},
"allrotation":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0,"w":1.0},"allscale":{"x":1.0,"y":1.0},
"linepos0":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"linepos1":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0,"z":0.0},"movetype":4}],
"NoteValues":[{"movenumber":4,"notemsg":"Added four"}]}]
```

Class given below.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerHandler 
{
public int id; 
public Vector2 allposition;
public Quaternion allrotation;
public Vector2 allscale;

public Vector3 linepos0;
public Vector3 linepos1;
public int movetype;


public PlayerHandler(int ids,Vector2 allpos,Quaternion allrot,Vector2 allscal,Vector3 Line0,Vector3 Line1,int Moves)

{
    this.id = ids;
    this.allposition = allpos;
    this.allrotation = allrot;
    this.allscale = allscal;
    this.linepos0 = Line0;
    this.linepos1 = Line1;
    this.movetype = Moves;
}



}

[System.Serializable]
public class PlayerMovement
{
public int movenumber;
public string notemsg;

public PlayerMovement(int Movenum,string Note)
{
    this.movenumber = Movenum;
    this.notemsg = Note;

}

}
```

Now I have two list with their corresponding values.

```
List<PlayerHandler> SaveValuesDeserialize = new List<PlayerHandler>();
List<PlayerMovement> NoteValuesDeserialzeList = new List<PlayerMovement>();
```

I would like to combine the above two lists into a third list with the 0th element from NoteValuesDeserialzeList[0],its 1st element from SaveValuesDeserialize[0],2nd element from NoteValuesDeserialzeList[1],3rd element from SaveValuesDeserialize[1] till all the values are added up.

Various doubts arises. What will be the object of the newly added list `List<?>AllcombinedList =new List<?>();`.

also what will be the count to add up the new list(the combined count of two list)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184764/storing-different-types-inside-a-list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing different types inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9184764/storing-different-types-inside-a-list)

Comment: Flagging the question as duplicate is ignoring the heart of the question.

Comment: i think really what it would be good to know is why do you want to do this?  No you can't have different types in a list as people have said but there are other ways you could store this data but it depends what you want to do

Comment: I want to get it all in a single List so that I can use it with next and previous button.I need to use counter++ and counter-- to use it.Otherwise it will be really a hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the only ancestor of PlayerHandler and PlayerMovement is object, you can only create a List of Objects:

```
List<object> AllcombinedList = new List<object>();

int count = Math.Min(SaveValuesDeserialize.Count, NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count);
// Or raise an exception if SaveValuesDeserialize.Count != NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count
// Or ask the user what to do with the rest if it can happen
// Else use count = SaveValuesDeserialize.Count for example if always same
for ( int index = 0; index < count; index++ )
{
  AllcombinedList.Add(NoteValuesDeserialzeList[index]);
  AllcombinedList.Add(SaveValuesDeserialize[index]);
}
```

Perhaps you may use a List of Tuples to acheive your goal:

```
var AllcombinedList = new List<Tuple<PlayerHandler, PlayerMovement>>();

int count = Math.Min(SaveValuesDeserialize.Count, NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count);
// Or raise an exception if SaveValuesDeserialize.Count != NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count
// Or ask the user what to do with the rest if it can happen
// Else use count = SaveValuesDeserialize.Count for example if always same
for ( int index = 0; index < count; index++ )
{
  var item = new Tuple<PlayerMovement, PlayerHandler>(NoteValuesDeserialize[index],
                                                      SaveValuesDeserialzeList[index]);
  AllcombinedList.Add(item);
}
```

Or anonymous tuples:

```
var AllcombinedList = new List<(PlayerHandler, PlayerMovement)>();

int count = Math.Min(SaveValuesDeserialize.Count, NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count);
// Or raise an exception if SaveValuesDeserialize.Count != NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count
// Or ask the user what to do with the rest if it can happen
// Else use count = SaveValuesDeserialize.Count for example if always same
for ( int index = 0; index < count; index++ )
{
  AllcombinedList.Add((NoteValuesDeserialize[index], SaveValuesDeserialzeList[index]));
}
```

Or you can create a class offering typing as well as naming:

```
var AllcombinedList = new List<PlayerItem>();

int count = Math.Min(SaveValuesDeserialize.Count, NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count);
// Or raise an exception if SaveValuesDeserialize.Count != NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count
// Or ask the user what to do with the rest if it can happen
// Else use count = SaveValuesDeserialize.Count for example if always same
for ( int index = 0; index < count; index++ )
  AllcombinedList.Add(new PlayerItem
  {
    Movement = NoteValuesDeserialzeList[index],
    Handler = SaveValuesDeserialize[index]
  });

public class PlayerItem
{
  public PlayerMovement Movement { get; set; }
  public PlayerHandler Handler { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to manage additional items you can for example do that:

```
int count = Math.Max(SaveValuesDeserialize.Count, NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count);
for ( int index = 0; index < count; index++ )
{
  var movement = index < NoteValuesDeserialzeList.Count 
               ? NoteValuesDeserialzeList[index] 
               : null;
  var handler = index < SaveValuesDeserialize.Count 
              ? SaveValuesDeserialize[index] 
              : null;
  AllcombinedList.Add(new PlayerItem
  {
    Movement = movement,
    Handler = handler
  });
}
```

You must decide yourself what to do with additional items (when one of the counts is more than the other): do nothing, add the other as null or create a default instance.

Comment: I tried the last code of your solution.SaveValuesDeserialize count is 10 and NoteValuesDeserialzeList count is 4.So it will take only minimum count.Then how will it add all the values of SaveValuesDeserialize from `for ( int index = 0; index < count; index++ )
  AllcombinedList.Add(new PlayerItem
  {
    Movement = NoteValuesDeserialzeList[index]
    Handler = SaveValuesDeserialize[index],
  });` I tried the code and but when I took the messages all the last messages was repeating.

Comment: Encountered a problem.I was trying to get two list and merge into one list so that I can easily use next button and previous button to implement getting data one by one.Since the length varies a bit confused.Updated the question with JSON.That logic wont work here i think.Since I want to initially show notemsg[0] value.Then when I click next button want to apply all the values of SaveValues[0].Then when I click next again notemsg[1] and when I click next SaveValues[1] and so on.But here I am adding list one by one.

Comment: [Asked here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-get-data-for-previous-button-while-i-am-getting-details-with-the-next-button.769739/#post-5126174)

Comment: How to get value from Allcombined list?

Comment: With List of Tuples: `AllcombinedList[0].Item1` and `.Item2`. With List of PlayerInfo: `AllcombinedList[0].Movement` and `.Handler`.

Answer (score -1):

A generic `List<T>` only accepts one type `T` in its definition. Therefore you can't have elements of varying types in it, all must be of same type.

You could use a `class` or a `struct` to hold and expose both data types and then use this class or structure as the type `T` in the generic `List<T>` definition. Alternatively, you can use [tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples).

If this approach seems too involved to you, then you can use as the type `T` for your `List<T>` the ancestor of both `PlayerHandler` and `PlayerMovement` which is `Object`.

Comment: boxing and unboxing only happens with value types and is where the value type (int) is wrapped in a object reference and moved to the heap.  The above types are classes i.e. reference types already created on the heap and so there is no boxing , you just have a list of object references to the PlayerHandler and PlayerMovement objects.