# Lists<> with multiple lists c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, list

I am searching for a solution to create `List<>` of Lists with different data types like 
`List<List<int>,List<double>,List<string>> list;`

or a `List<>` with multiple data types like 
`List<int,double,string> list;`

Comment: create List<iEnumerable>

Comment: What are you **actually** trying to do?

Comment: Suppose you _could_ do `List<int,double,string> list;`  What would the compile-time type of `list[0]` be?  You need a common base type = in this case, `object`.

Comment: It seems likely that there's a better approach to your problem. You should describe exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am developing a software for imputation that will impute categorical and numerical values so I was thinking to use same list to store different data types so that i don't have to parse values again and again. @cubrr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May be you can do like this

```
 public class Helper
    {
        public object value;
        private string Type;
    }
```

then create list

```
List<Helper> myList=new List<Helper>();
```

use like this

```
myList.Add(new Helper {value = 45,Type = "int"});
myList.Add(new Helper {value = 45,Type = "int"});
myList.Add(new Helper {value = "hello",Type = "string"});
```

and the covert according to *Type*.

Answer (score 10):

In all seriousness... ***why?***

The code which consumes these structures is going to be confusing and difficult to support.  It really, really will.

If you have a custom structure to your data, create a custom object to represent that structure.  Something like this:

```
class MyThing
{
    public int Widget { get; set; }
    public double Foo { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

Use *actual* meaningful names for your values/types/etc. of course, because that's the entire point of doing this.

Then just have a list of those:

```
var things = new List<MyThing>();
```

As your structure continues to change and grow, you build the logic of that structure *into the object itself*, rather than into all of the consuming code which uses it.  The code which uses it then more closely approximates the semantics of the operations it's trying to perform, rather than a dizzying assortment of syntactic operations.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a list of lists by

```
List<List<int>>
```

To have a list with multiple data types you could use a [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) which can take up to 8 items.

```
List<Tuple<string, int>>
List<Tuple<string, string, int>>
```

You could even go crazy and do the following

```
Tuple<List<int>, int, int> tuple = new Tuple<List<int>, int, int>(new List<int>(), 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly, I think you need a little helper class:

```
public class MyInfo {
    public int MyInt32 { get; set; }
    public double MyDouble { get; set; }
    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

Then, make a list of those: `var myList = new List<MyInfo>()`.

You can also use a `List<Tuple<int, double, string>>`, but I would recommend creating your own class if the scope of usage is wider than a single class, because `Tuples` properties aren't very descriptive as to what they are: `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3`...

Answer (score 1):

Best way to solve this is to use Interface you can find solution here [list of multiple data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343336/a-list-of-multiple-data-types)

Comment: While it is good suggestion (probably better be duplicate suggestion/comment rather than answer by the way), it is not helpful for OP as there is no shared interface between `int`, `double` and `string`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ArrayList - the old non generic list. THis allows you to put anything in it, int, string, FooObject, bool,....