# How to declare a list that contain an array with 2 types of data?

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have this list so far:

```
    List<object> lista = new List<object>();
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        lista.Add(new
        {
            ver = item.FirstOrDefault().vereda.DESCRIPCION,
            prod = item.Count()
        });
    }

    ViewBag.veredasEncu = lista;
```

i have to send that data to a view in order to build a table:

```
 <tbody>

 @{
     if (ViewBag.veredasEncu != null)
     {
         List<object> lis = ViewBag.veredasEncu;

         for (int i = 0; i < lis.Count(); i++)
         {
             <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             </tr>
         }
     }
  }

</tbody>
```

I cant get to place the info on the `<td>` tags cose every item in the `foreach` iteration throws something this:

```
item = {ver = "Loma", prod = 5}
```

how can i make that 2 values look like an array, or is there a way to separate them in order to place them in the correct tag?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343336/a-list-of-multiple-data-types

Comment: Not really usefull

Comment: Why can't you access these values in the for loop? Like `<td>@lis[i].ver</td>`

Comment: @Haldo because  `ver` isnt a part of the object. its like every item have an unique value or data that is displayed as `string="{ver = "Loma", prod = 5}"`. Anyway i found a way to solve it already.

Comment: then you should post your answer and mark it as correct

Comment: @Jonathan yup, i was typing this, however it would be great to find a more generic way to solve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by creating a class:

```
public class dataTab
{
    public string ver { get; set; }
    public int prod { get; set; }
}
```

then is just change the loop for this:

```
lista2.Add(new dataTab
            {
                 ver = item.FirstOrDefault().vereda.DESCRIPCION,
                 prod = item.Count()
            });
```

so it could be post in the HTML like this:

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.veredasEncu)
 {
    <tr>
       <td>@item.ver</td>
       <td>@item.prod</td>
    </tr>
 }
```

However im not sure that creating a class for every type of list that i need to create is a good idea. IF someone have an idea on how to fill the list in a more *generic* way please respond this.

Comment: In general, this is exactly how you should do this. These are called `viewmodels`. You could (maybe should) take it one step further and assign the viewmodel to the view, and not pass it in via the viewbag.

Comment: so it is still valid if i need to fill another 5 tables with different data? also for this case i dont think is good to pass the data as a viewmodel  for the same reason. As a teacher use to say, "it looks like spagueti code".

Comment: 'Spaghetti code' is not defined by the amount of code that you write, but by how it can get interconnected if it isn't structured correctly, and become difficult to untangle. There may be other ways to structure the viewmodels to reduce their number (for example, maybe `description` and `value` can be used for all of them, and you can share the same viewmodel for all tables), but I don't know without seeing the structures

Comment: actully it could be useful, it will be like dividing a 6 cm bread in 3 breads of 2 cm. thanks for the advice